# How does $7\log(8x) = 7\ln8x$?

Tags: logarithms

I was working on some math homework with a program called scientific notebook. I was check that I was writing something correctly.

The original equation is $(\log(x^4)+\log(x^5))/\log(8x)=7$

I then converted it to $\log(x^{(4+5)})=7\log(8x)$

I was expecting to get $\log((8x)^7)$ when I entered the $7\log(8x)$ into the program to evaluate. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: It sounds like your software interprets $\log$ and $\ln$ to mean the same thing.  If by $\log$ you intend the meaning to be log base $10$ or anything other than $\ln$, then you may adjust your use of the software to get it to take the correct meaning of your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In higher mathematics it is customary to take $\;\log=\ln=\log_e\;$ , and that's what most mathematicians mean when writing that.

**Added:** You had

$$\frac{\log x^4+\log x^5}{\log 8x}=7\iff \log x^9=7\log 8x=\log(8x)^7\implies$$

$$x^9=8^7x^7\implies x^2=8^7\ldots$$

Comment: But is log((8x)^7) still correct then?